# Template 10: Hide HamBurgerMenu if no internet

Tags: uwp, template10

I am devloping an uwp app in which if there is no internet then the user is shown an error  no internet connection at start.So I checked for internet connection if not then i did this in my App.xaml.:

```
 public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        // long-running startup tasks go here
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));  
           if (!NoInternet)
            {


                NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.Error));
            }             
            }         
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
```

Now when no internet connection is there then it navigates to my Error Page but the HamburgerMenu is still visible.How do i hide the HamburgerMenu.?I am using HamburgerMenu Template of Template10.Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into similar problem for my app.Assuming that you have not edited shell.xaml.cs and also the Hamburgermenu name,just add this into shall.xaml.cs

```
   public HamburgerMenu _THamburgerMenu
    {
        get { return MyHamburgerMenu;}

        set { MyHamburgerMenu = value;}
    }
```

and your app.xaml.cs should be like this:

```
public override async Task OnStartAsync(StartKind startKind, IActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    // long-running startup tasks go here
    await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6));  
       if (!NoInternet)
        {

            Shell.Instance._THamburgerMenu.IsFullScreen = true;

            NavigationService.Navigate(typeof(Views.Error));
        }             
        }         
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Ps:add using youappname.Views in app.xaml.cs

Comment: Sorry i made it lengthy just add this line before Navigation                `Shell.HamburgerMenu.IsFullScreen = true;`and do nothing in shell.xaml.cs

Answer (score 2):

To do this use the IsFullScreen property.

You can do it in the OnNavigationToAsync() going to the Errors page or do it at your logic check prior to navigation.

IsFullScreen = true;

The latest versions of the template 1.18 / library v1.1.11 have a property already setup for you in the SettingsService for IsFullScreen, keep in mind when it changes it gets persisted to the settings file.

Comment: Thanks it helped .I was confused how to use the IsFullScreen Property.